# Allowing HTTP connections to connect with iCal (SSL error)

Tags: macos, osx-server, ical

While attempting to connect to my iCal via another laptop I get an SSL error that looks like this:

[image]

Now I read somewhere that you can fix this by adding an `NSAppTransportSecurity` key to a `plist`, I've also read that allowing `8.8.8.8` in your DNS will do the trick as well. Neither of these have worked (could be because I didn't edit the right plist). Does anybody have any idea how to allow non-HTTPS connections into an iCal, or how to fix this SSL error?

Comment: Nobody has any ideas?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend allowing insecure connections. I sometimes have this problem with websites, have you tried switching Wi-Fi networks (or phone tethering)?

Comment: @seaturtle yeah I know allowing the connection is probably a bad idea, but there's a lot of pressure on me to get this connection running. The Wi-Fi network we are using is on the same IP range as the server, so that shouldn't be a problem.